# How to convert video *.ts to *.mp4 on the fly and playback it on web (node.js)

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video

Using the Node.js with 'fluent-ffmpeg' i may convert video stream from Live TV to mp4, so it is playing in HTML5 Video. 
What i have:

- incoming video is transport stream (the Live TV) which i receive by
  link from my server http://IP/stream/direct?channel=8724
- receive data from stream and write it to file, say **in.ts** , then this
  in.ts file i give to ffmpeg as an input file.
- this scheme works,
  But, i got a **short output file** from ffmpeg (out.mp4), even
  thought the in.ts grows constantly. FFmpeg converts only file size
  which was written at the time when ffmpeg starts to work.

I need somehow to say to FFmpeg, that incoming file is growing and need to wait new data for futher convertation ...

Also curious if there a way to give this out.mp4 file which should constantly grow to HTML5 video player.

Here is a code i have now:

```
let ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
let fs = require('fs');
let http = require('http');

let inStream = 'http://IP/stream/direct?channel=8724';
let inFileName = 'in.ts';
let inWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream(inFileName);

let isRun = false;
let request = http.get(inStream, (d) => {
  d.on('data', (d) => {
    inWriteStream.write(d);
    console.log(getSize());
    if (getSize() > 10 && !isRun) {
      startDecode();
      isRun = true;
    }
  });
})
  .on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });
function startDecode() {
  var infs = fs.createReadStream(inFileName);
  ffmpeg(infs)
    .save('out.mp4');
  console.log('Decoding....');
}

function getSize() {
  let stats = fs.statSync(inFileName);
  let fileSizeInBytes = stats.size;
  let fileSizeInMegabytes = fileSizeInBytes / 1000000.0;
  //size in Mb
  return fileSizeInMegabytes;
}
```

Comment: Can't ffmpeg take the input stream directly as an input?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I have tired got an error.

Comment: @laggingreflex seems i've done something wrong, as now ffmpeg gets http://link_to_stream as an input and seems to work)  At this point, one issue is left, the HTML 5 Video now can't play this out.mp4 video file.

Comment: Ok, in this case, decoding works, but file is not playable, even at VLC.  ffmpeg('link')
    .save('out.mp4');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard mp4 files can not be used for live video. MP4 files use a structure that encodes all frame sizes into a single location at the end (or beginning) of a file. Therefore, an mp4 is not playable until it is complete and this information is written. There is such a thing as “fragmented mp4” that makes little mp4s that can be played back to back.

Comment: Thank you for the point. Now, at least VLC player may play out.mp4 constantly 
    `.outputOptions('-c:v libx264')
    .outputOptions('-g 52')
    .outputOptions('-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov')
    .outputOptions('-f mp4')
    .save('./assets/out.mp4');`

Comment: So, as i undestand, there is no way to play even fragmented mp4 at HTML5 and i need some player which may re-read the length of file and not to stop playing already dowloaded part. Maybe there is some?